# Showing that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x = 1}^{20} \cos(x-10)^{2n} = 1\ $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

How do I show that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x = 1}^{20} \cos(x-10)^{2n} = 1\ ?$$

Comment: You should write $\cos^{2n}(x-10)$ or $[\cos(x-10)]^{2n}.$

Comment: @zhw. Well,  I think he wrote that correct because if the power $2n$ is on $cos $, then sum can't be zero for $n= 1$ to $20$ except for $n=10$.

Comment: @Vineet Mangal, the remark of zhw is correct(and I considered this in my solution), if the term were $\cos [(x-10)^{2n}]$ the statement wouldn't be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a finite sum, just show that $\cos(x-10)^{2n}\to 0$ except for $x=10$, where you get $1$.

Comment: Actually, except for $x=10+n\pi,n\in \mathbb Z.$

Comment: @zhw, sure but I was referring for the $x\in \{1,2,\dots,20\}$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the problem properly. Thanks.